# python-pptx change font size in a Table

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-pptx

Hello Community Members,

I am using python-pptx module to generate a table with some data. The table comes out with data as expected , but due to the font, it just goes out of the slide in all directions.

I am trying to reduce the font size of the text in table to make it fit into the slide,

the python-pptx documentation does mention that it can be done, but gives emphasis only on shapes, and not much on Tables,

from the Documentation here,

https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/text.html#applying-character-formatting

Does it mean that a table cell is also considered a shape ?

If it does , how can I use the same example below into my code at Bottom. Any Help in this regards is appreciated.

**SNIPPET from DOCUMENTATION**

=========================

**Applying text frame-level formatting**

The following produces a shape with a single paragraph, a slightly wider bottom than top margin (these default to 0.05”), no left margin, text aligned top, and word wrapping turned off. In addition, the auto-size behavior is set to adjust the width and height of the shape to fit its text. Note that vertical alignment is set on the text frame. Horizontal alignment is set on each paragraph:

```
from pptx.util import Inches
from pptx.enum.text import MSO_ANCHOR, MSO_AUTO_SIZE

text_frame = shape.text_frame
text_frame.text = 'Spam, eggs, and spam'
text_frame.margin_bottom = Inches(0.08)
text_frame.margin_left = 0
text_frame.vertical_anchor = MSO_ANCHOR.TOP
text_frame.word_wrap = False
text_frame.auto_size = MSO_AUTO_SIZE.SHAPE_TO_FIT_TEXT
```

The possible values for TextFrame.auto_size and TextFrame.vertical_anchor are specified by the enumeration MSO_AUTO_SIZE and MSO_VERTICAL_ANCHOR respectively.

========================================================================

**MY CODE :**

```
import pandas as pd
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.util import Inches
from PIL import Image

prs = Presentation()
title_only_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[5]
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(title_only_slide_layout)
shapes = slide.shapes

data =pd.read_csv('dest_file2.csv', sep=',',skiprows=[0],nrows=11)
shapes.title.text = 'Inbound Traffic'
rows = 6
cols = 7
left = top = Inches(2.0)
width = Inches(6.0)
height = Inches(0.8)

table = shapes.add_table(rows, cols, left, top, width, height).table

# set column widths
table.columns[0].width = Inches(2.0)
table.columns[1].width = Inches(1.0)

# write column headings
table.cell(0, 0).text = 'Server'
table.cell(0, 1).text = 'Client'
table.cell(0, 2).text = 'Port'
table.cell(0, 3).text = 'Avg Bits/s'
table.cell(0, 4).text = 'Avg Packets/s'
table.cell(0, 5).text = 'Total Bytes'
table.cell(0, 6).text = 'Total Packets'

print(data)

a = data['Server']
b = data['Client']
c = data['Port']
d = data['Avg Bits/s']
e = data['Avg Packets/s']
f = data['Total Bytes']
g = data['Total Packets']
i=1
j=0
size = len(a)-1
while j < size:
    # write body cells
    table.cell(i, 0).text = a[j]
    table.cell(i, 1).text = b[j]
    table.cell(i, 2).text = c[j]
    table.cell(i, 3).text = str(d[j])
    table.cell(i, 4).text = str(e[j])
    table.cell(i, 5).text = str(f[j])
    table.cell(i, 6).text = str(g[j])
    print(a[j],b[j],c[j],d[j],e[j],f[j],g[j])
    i=i+1
    j=j+1

prs.save('test.pptx')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to know that table cells contain text frames which contain paragraphs which contain runs. A run has a font object and you can specify the size for the font there.